# Deleting User Roles Using SSJS in Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am trying to delete the user roles and permissions using SSJS (payload) in Marketing Cloud. I was able to add and update the roles, but I don't know if i can delete the roles.

I was successful in updating the roles. The problem is when I try to update the roles it gets appended to the old roles. Basically, I want to remove the old roles and assign a new role.

Any sample code would really be appreciated.

Comment: I keep getting "Error" when updating roles via SSJS. `<script runat="server" language="javascript">
   Platform.Load("core","1.1");
  var acctUserInit = AccountUser.Init("xxxxx-xxxx-xx-x-x", 100001234);
var status = acctUserInit.Update({"Roles" : "b7976154-cbda-e711-a2c3-1402ec8ca148"});
Write(Stringify(status));` Any glaring errors?